# jq: parse and display multiple values in JSON

Tags: bash, while-loop, jq, ifs

I have this `test.json` file

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "expand": "xx",
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "self": "https",
      "key": "test-11",
      "fields": {
        "field_1": "1234"
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "xx",
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "self": "https",
      "key": "test-10",
      "fields": {
        "field_1": "1235",
        "field_2": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to read the values using IFS while loops:

```
cat test.json| jq -r '[.list[]| ([.key]|tostring) + "," + "\(.fields| .field_1)"]|@tsv' \
| while IFS="," read -r key field_1; do
echo "$key $field_1"
curl -s https ://thisistest.com/api/$key/$field_1
done;
echo output displays only: test-11
```

I would like to get the values of  `key` and `field_1` to use them in the `curl` request.

Comment: Try: `jq -r '.list[]|[.key,.fields.field_1]|@tsv' test.json`

Comment: @att , I have rollbacked this question to its previous version. The json modification you have made resulted to invalid json file, with `::` at some points. Furthermore, if you have any more questions, different than the initial question, please raise a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jq` command from @Kev in comment will extract the values you want, each pair per line, like this:

```
> jq -r '.list[]|[.key,.fields.field_1]|@tsv' test.json
test-11 1234
test-10 1235
```

Here is how you can modify your script to make your `curl` requests per value pair.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r key field_1; do
    echo curl -s https://thisistest.com/api/$key/$field_1
done < <( jq -r '.list[]|[.key,.fields.field_1]|@tsv' test.json )
```

Remove `echo` if you are ok with your testing.

Comment: thank you! that worked to get the field1 value.I'm also trying to get the name value in field 2  -  jq -r '.list[]|[.key,.fields.field_2.name]|@tsv' test.json but getting error cannot iterate over null (null)